# Recurring permissions problems w/ Laravel on vagrant box

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, vagrant

I'm getting some strange permissions problems. I'm using Laravel on a vagrant box. I regularly have to reset my `app/storage` permissions.

Here's my process:

- in terminal, run `sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage`. I do this both from the vagrant ssh and directly on my machine.
- everything loads fine.
- I run a login script that looks like this:

  ```
  public function store()
  {
  $input = Input::all();

  $attempt = Auth::attempt([
      'email' => $input['email']
      , 'password' => $input['password']
  ]);

  if($attempt){
      return Redirect::intended('/');
  }else{
      dd('errors');
  }
  }
  ```
- I fill in my login with incorrect details & I get the `dd()` output as expected.
- I return to my login form.
- I enter valid user details.
- I get the following permissions error:

  ```
  file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel/app/storage/sessions/62da397f3ec526dea6cabf36f06657234dfb9de7): failed to open stream: Permission denied
  ```
- In terminal I run `sudo chmod -R app/storage` again.
- I can reload the page and the permissions denied error is gone.

I've done this consistently every. single. time. I can't work out what's messing with my permissions or how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just figured it out. it's to do with the vagrantfile. I added the owner and group info to the synced files and it's working now.

```
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :owner => 'www-data', :group => 'www-data'
```

Comment: I have this issue on a production server with ubuntu. Any idea what might cause it?

Comment: Once I added the change to my vagrant file it went away so I suspect it was an issue with how vagrant recognizes which folders should be synced and doesn't give permission to others.

Comment: The above would like like this as of Vagrant 1.9.1 `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"`. See [Vagrant Synced Folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html#modifying-the-owner-group)

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following and it works for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Change the following paramaters:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

To:

```
user = vagrant
group = vagrant
```

Remember to restart PHP FPM

```
sudo service php7.3-fpm restart
```

Comment: Helpful for me @Boon :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

php has chance to run session gc after every session_start(), i.e. delete all session files you set before.